# Is it possible to install a new locale on Mac OS X server?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mac-osx-server

I'm running a php app on a Mac Server OS X 10.6 with fully functional apache 2 server. The app is intended to run in Mexico, but there's no es_MX locale on the server. How might I install it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [SU answer](https://superuser.com/a/344127) might provide the info that you're looking for:

> It's just directories containing text files. Mix and match to your
>   preferences.
>
> You can create a copy of en_ES and edit LC_CURRENCY by either copying
>   from another locale definition or editing all settings yourself. The
>   settings are documented [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html), in section 7.3.3 LC_MONETARY. One entry
>   per line

Assuming you know the appropriate values for the locale that you're setting up, you can make a copy of an existing locale and edit to include the locale-specific values.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As soon as I might vote this the best answer I will !!!